# Sonar Vs Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sonarqube

Can we compare Jenkins and Sonar ?
If yes how. 
I want to know advantage/disadvantage of Jenkins and Sonar.
Like why one should use Sonar and what advantage it has over Jenkins and vice versa?

Comment: Hi Draco, thanks for your reply. Can you give me some limitations of Jenkins which you have faced any time. Or can you list some limitation of Jenkins you know.

Comment: One more Question - Why Jenkins is Used and Why Sonar is Used ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Can we compare Jenkins and Sonar?

No.

**[Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Meet+Jenkins)** is a tool to implement [Continuous Integration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration).  The quick summary of which is integrating, building and testing code every time a change is made.

**[Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/)** is "a tool for managing code quality."  It focuses on analyzing code.

BTW, as a note that they play different roles in development, there is a Jenkins Plugin for integrating with Sonar. See the discussion here: [Why use sonar plugin for Jenkins rather than simply use maven goal "sonar:sonar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688139/why-use-sonar-plugin-for-jenkins-rather-than-simply-use-maven-goal-sonarsonar)