# passing sonar parameter to maven through hudson

Tags: maven, hudson, sonarqube

Have set up code analysis using sonar hudson and maven 
My plan is to run the analysis everyday  so I am trying to pass the parameter in Hudson as :

```
clean install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports **-Dsonar.projectDate=yyyy-     MM-dd**
```

Rather than entering / changing date everyday manually - is there a way I can make it a parameter which automatically changes everyday ?
Thanks
satish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the date/time of execution? Could you try to use -Dsonar.projectDate=${BUILD_ID} as a parameter? Check out localhost:8080/env-vars.html for available arguments you can pass to the sonar plugin.

Comment: Steve - thank you - this is exactly what I was looking for  and I did not know about the environment variables page ( http://localhost:8080/hudson-3.0.0/env-vars.html)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use "-Dsonar.projectDate": it is used only when you want to replay some analyses in the past. So you can just drop this parameter, Sonar will take the current date to timestamp your analysis.

Also, consider using the Sonar Hudson/Jenkins Plugin instead of calling directly Maven, this will help you: http://docs.codehaus.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=116359341

Comment: Fabrice - thanks for the response  - hwoever I am still not very clear on advantage of the plugin Vs direct maven call - I understand that plugin gives a nice GUI making it easier for data entry and understandability - but any other advantage that I get ? Thanks for your answer !

Comment: I already gave a clear answer on that topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688139/why-use-sonar-plugin-for-jenkins-rather-than-simply-use-maven-goal-sonarsonar/10688383#10688383