# What is the advantage of the Jenkins SonarQube plugin over adding sonar:sonar to maven build step

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I am using Maven as a build tool and Jenkins as a CI tool. Currently I have a Jenkins job configured with a Maven build step.

I started using SonarQube and was wondering what is the advantage of using the Jenkins SonarQube plugin and configuring the SonarQube analysis as a post-build-action over simply adding sonar:sonar to the goals of my existing Maven build step.

Thanks and best regards,

Ronald

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found: [Why use sonar plugin for Jenkins rather than simply use maven goal "sonar:sonar"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688139/why-use-sonar-plugin-for-jenkins-rather-than-simply-use-maven-goal-sonarsonar)

And to add one reason: Using the Jenkins SonarQube plugins one can specify "Skip if triggered by SCM Changes". This is nice if you trigger your Jenkins job for each commit but only want to do a SonarQube analysis at a scheduled time, e.g. one per night.

And here is a summary of the the points made by "emelendez":

- Centralize database credentials and sonar credentials Use jenkins
- Use jenkins sonar plugin configuring SonarRunner for non Java projects

Answer (score 1):

You can save a lot of configuration. So, if you use jenkins sonar plugin you can centralize database credentials and sonar credentials but if you make a decision about execute **sonar:sonar** in each jenkins job you will configure each with the same credentials.

Comment: Thanks your your reply. I can see your point about centralizing credentials - but I am not sure about saving "a lot" of configuration. If I execute sonar:sonar I just have to add the configuration to Maven's settings.xml. One thing I noticed is that in Maven's settings.xml I just specify the DB credentials and in the Jenkins SonarQube plugin I also specify the credentials of a sonar account. Do you know why this is necessary for the plugin? Is there some functionallity I have not seen yet in the plugin which needs the sonar credentials?

Comment: One more thing, you can also use jenkins sonar plugin configuring SonarRunner for non Java projects. And for security purpose you can edit sonar configuration from Jenkins UI instead edit settings.xml because not everyone can access to the server.

Answer (score 0):

I've just changed to `maven-sonar-plugin` from the Jenkins SonarQube plugin to avoid divergence of information between the `pom.xml` and `sonar-project.properties`.

For example, developers elsewhere had bumped the project version number in the `pom.xml`, but they don't use the Jenkins builds and didn't care about the `sonar-project.properties` (or probably understand it).  By switching to the maven plugin instead, the project version is defined once and referenced in the sonar property set within the pom.

The downside is that I no longer have the SonarQube link from the project's Jenkins page.

I'm not sure where the responsibility might be for adding this link back for projects using maven-sonar-plugin...  The link is "owned" by the Jenkins SonarQube Plugin, but this is not being used here.  Meanwhile the maven-sonar-plugin component is integrating with maven not Jenkins.

Something would need to observe the build and extract the SonarQube link which is emitted as a `[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://...` line in the log.